postgres primary key not incrementing on insert (pgloader migration)
I have been trying to migrate my db to PostgreSQL 16.3 from MariaDB
since I have some issue with some tables not creating a unique id on insert. Most work fine, but a few for some reason do not work properly
Here is a basic insert:
INSERT INTO brand (name, slug) VALUES ('moudle', 'moudle');

Result:

duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idx_18070_primary"

I'm new to PostgreSQL, and I'm not sure what could be going wrong and what to check.
I used pgloader and maybe forgot a setting?
LOAD DATABASE
     FROM      mysql://root:root@database/dev
     INTO      pgsql://app:pass@postgres/dev

 WITH include drop, create tables

CAST type json to jsonb
WITH prefetch rows = 100,
    preserve index names

 ALTER SCHEMA 'dev' RENAME TO 'public';


EDIT:
I just noticed that my problematic table for some reason does not have id_seq file as you can see from the table listing of Postbird. All other tables have it.


does that error occur during migration or after migration process?

after the migration


EDIT: I just noticed that my problematic table for some reason does
not have id_seq file as you can see from the table listing of
Postbird. All other tables have it.

The problem is an auto-generate id out of sync. To find out what kind of auto-generated id is your column you could run
select * from information_schema.columns
where table_name='brand';

if id column has a default value (column default in the form nextval('<sequence_name>'::regclass)), then its explicitly associated with a sequence, or if it is marked as identity its implicitly associated with a sequence, to put them back on sync
for the first case (explicit sequence)
select setval('<name of the sequence in the default value>',
coalesce(max(id), 0) + 1, false) from brand;

for an identity (implicit)
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('brand', 'id'), 
coalesce(max(id), 0) + 1, false) from brand;

Fiddle to test
And to avoid this problems after migration in the first place you could also use the WITH option "reset sequences" as appears in pgloader official documentation.

I ran the commands and have a brand_id_seq file and its value is 267 like it should be. But it seems that POSTGRES is not following it. I tried to create a new brand and got error id 15 already exists, trying again 16 and so on. so for some reason it seems to be following another count than the one in the seq file ?

If already exists and its current value is correct, then assign it to the table as I mentioned alter table public.brand alter column id set default nextval('brand_id_seq'); Or run select column_name, column_default from information_schema.columns where table_name='brand' and column_default is not null;
and mention what results

If I run the first command I get column "id" of relation "brand" is an identity column and the second one I get a column listing but there is no id in there

@Sam seems that your sequence is out of sync, I modified the answer according to your comments but you should edit your question adding that info for completion, and also should add a complete definition (DDL) of your problematic table.

Thanks I will try the reset sequence way since ideally it should work right after import. will probably take me a few days to work it out. will accept you answer when done.

I managed to make it work using pgloader. It works right after pgloader BUT turns out that I had another issue. Doctrine migration is generating $this->addSql('ALTER INDEX idx_16405_idx_574cfb894f34d596 RENAME TO IDX_574CFB894F34D596')X so as soon as I migrate I have the same error again.

What error is that? If it is duplicate key reset your sequence or if is on the index drop and create again.

It is hard to explain; I don't understand it very well myself. If I execute my pgloader file with reset_sequence then the table is created and there are NO id_seq files at all BUT everything works perfect. Now with doctrine I generate a migration file to put everything in sync and doctrine THEN creates id_seq files and nothing works anymore.

What is doctrine? If you are going to implement continuous migration check out this http://mysqltopgsql.com/project/
